# Hibernate mapping association OneToMany with constraint restriction

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I have the following code:

```
@Entity
class A{
  @Id
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<B> bs =new ArrayList<B>();
...
}

@Entity
class B{
  ...

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "aId", nullable = false)
  private A a;
}
```

I want hibernate NOT to persist A if bs.isEmpty().

with this code, hibernate persists A even though it has no B objects inside.

Do you know any solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add a constraint using annotations.

I think what you ask can be done implementing an **Event Listener**, which receives all the inserts which are being done. See the [Hibernate manual, chapter 12.2 - The Event System](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html), and the [javadoc for PreInsertEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/event/PreInsertEventListener.html). Specifically, I believe that this method may be useful to you:

```
boolean     onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event)
          Return true if the operation should be vetoed
```

From the event passed, you get the instance of the object that will be inserted through the method `getEntity()` of the [PreInsertEvent](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/event/PreInsertEvent.html).
Return true in the onPreInsert method and you'll stop the insert.

Remember to install the listener in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.